# What's the difference between @property and @synthesize?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, properties

Like I understand, @synthesize actually is generating the Getters and Setters. But what's @property then doing? Is it just setting up the parameters for that cool @synthesize magic function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You write @property in header file

```
@property float value;
```

is equivalent to:

```
- (float)value; 
- (void)setValue:(float)newValue;
```

It get information for OTHER classes, that your class has this methods

@synthesize phisicaly CREATE these methods in class implementation

Comment: It's not exactly equivalent: using @property also allows you to use dot-notation, e.g. object.value, object.value = 1.0f;

Answer (score 10):

`@property` declares the name as a property. This means, it will be accessible via the dot syntax (`object.value`).

`@synthetize` can be seen as a macro, that creates the getter and setter methods. It is useful to know that you can override those methods, even if you type have the `@synthetize` in place.

Comment: It's important to note, however, that methods declared as usual are accessible via the dot syntax, not just properties (though I would never recommend using dot syntax for anything that isn't a getter or setter). And, more importantly, without @synthesize, your properties aren't accessible by *any* method. If you use @property without @synthesize, it's exactly like declaring getter and setter methods, but never implementing them.

Answer (score 4):

`@property` declares getter and/or setter

`@synthesize` implements them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a common misconception that the @synthesize directive is required in order to implement setters and getters created with the @property directive, but this is not the case. Using the @property directive without @synthesize will still generate setters/getters and allow you to use dot notation. However, leaving out the @synthesize directive will cause the compiler to generate corresponding instance variables with a leading underscore character, e.g. the property myVar will have an instance variable of _myVar.

Using a leading underscore is a common convention that allows you to differentiate between properties and instance variables. It is also common for properties and instance variables to share the same name, which is what @synthesize does by default.

Comment: this wasnt the case back when the question was asked.

Comment: Also, if you override all of the accessors for any reason, an instance variable will not be synthesized automatically for you unless you manually `@synthesize`.